# extracting a particular diagonal form a data frame

Tags: r, database, dataframe, matrix

I am trying to get a particular diagonal from my data. This is my code :

```
a2008=c(30,50,65)
a2009=c(40,90,NA)
a2010=c(55,NA,NA)

mydata=rbind(a2008,a2009,a2010)
mydata
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
a2008   30   50   65
a2009   40   90   NA
a2010   55   NA   NA
```

how can we get the diagonal 65, 90, 55 ?

I already used the `diag` function but i got `30, 90, NA`.

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the main anti-diagonal, you can do this. (`rev` to get stated order)

```
mydata[row(mydata) + col(mydata) == ncol(mydata) + 1]
```

You can get the diagonal below that with

```
mydata[row(mydata) + col(mydata) == ncol(mydata) + 2]
```

and so on

Answer (score 3):

you can try to get the antidiagonal by

```
diag(mydata[,nrow(mydata):1])
[1] 65 90 55
```

or

```
diag(as.matrix(rev(as.data.frame(mydata))))
```

Comment: Or use `ncol`, so it will work with non-square matrices

Comment: oh yes. good point!

Answer (score 2):

You can get that diagonal by flipping your matrix before calling `diag`:

```
diag(mydata[ , 3:1]) # [1] 65 90 55
```

Doing `mydata[ , 3:1]` is indexing the columns of your matrix in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

That's a matrix, not a data frame. Which is good! Diagonals of data frames don't make much sense. I would do it like this:

```
mydata[cbind(1:3, 3:1)]
# [1] 65 90 55
```

You can use a matrix to index a matrix, this is saying you want the values from rows 1, 2, 3 and columns 3, 2, 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by first flipping the matrix and them finding the diagonal.  That is

```
diag(apply(mydata, 1, rev))
```

I hope this helps!